# Create an array from the output of POST request in JSON Object

Tags: httprequest, azure-logic-apps, kql, azure-resource-graph

I'm trying to send an email via Logic App.
The content must be an array of an orphaned resources.

I am using an HTTP request to query the Azure resource graph explorer, on the Output I have a JSON object. I want to transform this JSON Object on an array.

[image]
How to get an array from the output of HTTP POST request?

Comment: Do you want the content of the "data" object to be pasted as the body into your email?

Comment: Yes , I want on the body of email, a array of data , now I just have json format which are paste without space and its unreadle.

Comment: Can you post the JSON into the question so we can use it to answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it worked for me:

Taking provided JSON into consideration Instead of having body as From data in Create HTML table I have used `data` since the Create HTML table takes only array as input and then modified the same while sending the email.

Here is my Logic app :
[image]

Here is the email :
[image]

### Updated Answer

Here is the whole logic app

[image]

For parse JSON I'm generating the schema using sample payload with the same JSON that you have provided with sample values. i.e..

```
{
  "body": {
    "totalRecords": 25,
    "count": 25,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "SampleId",
        "diskState": "Sample",
        "resourceGroup": "dkfdfjsi",
        "location": "gareg",
        "subscriptionId": "fgser"
      },
      {
        "id": "SampleID2",
        "diskState": "SAmple2",
        "resourceGroup": "dkfdfjsi",
        "location": "gareg",
        "subscriptionId": "fgser"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As your requirement is to send the data in a tabular format I have used the same connector as you did i.e. `Create HTML Table` with `data` array as input to the connector and so it will be generating the table automatically with the headers in the format mentioned below

[image]

Lastly, I have used the output of the HTML Table connector to send the email

[image]

Here is the code view of my logic app

```
{
   "definition": {
       "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
       "actions": {
           "Create_HTML_table_2": {
               "inputs": {
                   "format": "HTML",
                   "from": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['data']"
               },
               "runAfter": {
                   "Parse_JSON": [
                       "Succeeded"
                   ]
               },
               "type": "Table"
           },
           "Parse_JSON": {
               "inputs": {
                   "content": "@triggerBody()",
                   "schema": {
                       "properties": {
                           "body": {
                               "properties": {
                                   "count": {
                                       "type": "integer"
                                   },
                                   "data": {
                                       "items": {
                                           "properties": {
                                               "diskState": {
                                                   "type": "string"
                                               },
                                               "id": {
                                                   "type": "string"
                                               },
                                               "location": {
                                                   "type": "string"
                                               },
                                               "resourceGroup": {
                                                   "type": "string"
                                               },
                                               "subscriptionId": {
                                                   "type": "string"
                                               }
                                           },
                                           "required": [
                                               "id",
                                               "diskState",
                                               "resourceGroup",
                                               "location",
                                               "subscriptionId"
                                           ],
                                           "type": "object"
                                       },
                                       "type": "array"
                                   },
                                   "totalRecords": {
                                       "type": "integer"
                                   }
                               },
                               "type": "object"
                           }
                       },
                       "type": "object"
                   }
               },
               "runAfter": {},
               "type": "ParseJson"
           },
           "Send_an_email_(V2)_2": {
               "inputs": {
                   "body": {
                       "Body": "<p><strong>Total Records</strong> :@{body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['totalRecords']} , &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Count </strong>: @{body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['count']}<br>\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>\n@{body('Create_HTML_table_2')}</p>",
                       "Subject": "Sample Test",
                       "To": "<YOUR REQUIRED EMAIL ID>"
                   },
                   "host": {
                       "connection": {
                           "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                       }
                   },
                   "method": "post",
                   "path": "/v2/Mail"
               },
               "runAfter": {
                   "Create_HTML_table_2": [
                       "Succeeded"
                   ]
               },
               "type": "ApiConnection"
           }
       },
       "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
       "outputs": {},
       "parameters": {
           "$connections": {
               "defaultValue": {},
               "type": "Object"
           }
       },
       "triggers": {
           "manual": {
               "inputs": {},
               "kind": "Http",
               "type": "Request"
           }
       }
   },
   "parameters": {
       "$connections": {
           "value": {
               "office365": {
                   "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>/resourceGroups/<YOUR RESOURCE GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                   "connectionName": "office365",
                   "id": "/subscriptions/<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/office365"
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible to have the complete Logic app please ?

Comment: It will be interesting to have datails about each step

Comment: @Makina74 Can you please check the updated answer

Comment: thank you for the return but , where have you set query ? Possible to see the content of your trigger ?

Comment: @Makina74 Through trigger I'm just sending the JSON that you have mentioned. Probably You can follow the above workflow from Parse JSON step of yours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241206/discussion-between-swethakandikonda-mt-and-makina74).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a specific schema in the [parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action) action to have it be parsed into (an array of) objects, if that structure is known.

> To reference or access properties in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) content, you can create user-friendly fields or tokens for those properties by using the **Parse JSON** action. That way, you can select those properties from the dynamic content list when you specify inputs for your logic app. For this action, you can either provide a JSON schema or generate a JSON schema from your sample JSON content or payload.

The article [Perform data operations in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations) shows examples of exactly what you're trying to achieve, looking at your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

@SwethaKandikonda-MT
[image]

I use recurence as trigger. After I use http connector to querying Azure resource graph to obtain the result of kql request.
after the http i have a result in json object. I use as you , a Parse Json with the same schema. I create after a html table with data from the parse Json but when i run the loguc app , it makes an error because the from of html table is considered as null